# Timing jquery background parallax effect

Tags: jquery, parallax, timing

I made jQuery parallax that works fine when its on top of the page, however when i mover it to the bottom of page by the time i scroll down it already completely off from the view.

Below i made 3 parallax images evenly distributed on the page (elements between this images have same height) so i can safely adjust each next parallax image to be twice slower than previous one then by time i scroll to end of page it more or less even i am sure i could calculate timing more precisely

However if i increase spacing between first and second parallax images then timing will have to change, is there better way to make it work?

I think one of possibilities is knowing distance from top of the page to the top of the parallax image (e.g. 600px) then only when scroll bar reaches to say 300px we can start parallaxing first image, but is this a proper way to do it?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TkmLy/2/

jQuery

```
$('section').scroll(function(){
    var x = $(this).scrollTop();
    $(this).find(".bg1").css('background-position','0% '+parseInt(-x/2)+'px');
    $(this).find(".bg2").css('background-position','0% '+parseInt(-x/4)+'px');
    $(this).find(".bg3").css('background-position','0% '+parseInt(-x/6)+'px');
});
```

css

```
<style>
    html, body{
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    section {
        overflow-y:scroll;
        height:100%;
    }

    .bg1{
        width:100%;
        height:300px;
        background: #cccccc url(http://demo.rocknrolladesigns.com/wp/jarvis/callouts/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/parallax4.jpg) no-repeat fixed 0 0; 
    }

    .bg2{
        width:100%;
        height:300px;
        background: #cccccc url(http://demo.rocknrolladesigns.com/wp/jarvis/callouts/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/slider2.jpg) no-repeat fixed 0 0; 
    }

    .bg3{
        width:100%;
        height:300px;
        background: #cccccc url(http://demo.rocknrolladesigns.com/wp/jarvis/callouts/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/sunset-hair.jpg) no-repeat fixed 0 0; 
    }

 </style>
```

html

```
<section>

 xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>

 <div class="bg1"></div>

xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>

<div class="bg2"></div>

xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>

<div class="bg3"></div>

xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>xxx<br/>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For parallax background images, you need to have `background-attachment: fixed;`

The way parallax background images are calculated is more complex then that, I suggest to just use this library here. It's used by a great number of themes and templates currently.

https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax/

Comment: if you look closer it is fixed "background: #aa0000 url(...) no-repeat **fixed** 0 0;"

Comment: I know about this library and on purpose i dont want to study way they did it, but want to do my own code to learn to do it rather than include libraries.

Comment: I used to think as you think, about calculating the background image only when the user reached the parallax section, but in the end it's really confusing and I just stick with the logic in this library.

It's simple, just multiply the distance between the element's position and how far the user has scrolled with the speedFactor.

Comment: currentBackgroundPosition = ( element.offset().top - window.scrollTop() ) * speedFactor